# Apache Spark standalone for Anonymous UID (Without user name)

Tags: apache-spark, docker, openshift

I am starting Apache spark slave node on OpenShift platform. OpenShift internally start the docker image as an Anonymous user (User without name but just UID). I am getting following exception

```
17/07/17 16:46:53 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for INT
12  17/07/17 16:46:55 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
13  Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: failure to login
14      at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:824)
15      at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:761)
16      at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:634)
17      at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2391)
18      at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2391)
19      at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
20      at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getCurrentUserName(Utils.scala:2391)
21      at org.apache.spark.SecurityManager.<init>(SecurityManager.scala:221)
22      at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker$.startRpcEnvAndEndpoint(Worker.scala:714)
23      at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker$.main(Worker.scala:696)
24      at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker.main(Worker.scala)
25  Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: java.lang.NullPointerException: invalid null input: name
26      at com.sun.security.auth.UnixPrincipal.<init>(UnixPrincipal.java:71)
27      at com.sun.security.auth.module.UnixLoginModule.login(UnixLoginModule.java:133)
28      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
29      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
30      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
31      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
32      at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:755)
33      at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:195)
34      at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:682)
35      at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:680)
36      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
37      at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
38      at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587)
39      at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:799)
40      at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:761)
41      at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:634)
42      at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2391)
43      at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2391)
44      at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
45      at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getCurrentUserName(Utils.scala:2391)
46      at org.apache.spark.SecurityManager.<init>(SecurityManager.scala:221)
47      at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker$.startRpcEnvAndEndpoint(Worker.scala:714)
48      at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker$.main(Worker.scala:696)
49      at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker.main(Worker.scala)
50  
51      at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:856)
52      at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:195)
53      at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:682)
54      at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:680)
55      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
56      at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
57      at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587)
58      at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:799)
59      ... 10 more
```

I tried setting following properties on spark-default.conf still no use.

```
spark.eventLog.enabled             false
spark.ui.enabled                   false
spark.acls.enable                  false
spark.admin.acls                   *
spark.modify.acls                  *
spark.modify.acls.groups           *
spark.ui.view.acls.groups          *
spark.ui.enabled                   false
```

Could you please help me on this issue.

Thanks

Naveen

Answer (score 6):

Here is an alternative approach that doesn't require `nss_wrapper`.

By default, OpenShift containers run with an anonymous user id, and group id `0` (aka the "root" group).  First, set up your images so that `/etc/passwd` is owned by group-id `0`, and has group write access, for example this Dockerfile snippet:

```
RUN chgrp root /etc/passwd && chmod ug+rw /etc/passwd
```

Then you can add the following logic at container startup, for example the following script can be used as an `ENTRYPOINT`:

```
#!/bin/bash

myuid=$(id -u)
mygid=$(id -g)
uidentry=$(getent passwd $myuid)

if [ -z "$uidentry" ] ; then
    # assumes /etc/passwd has root-group (gid 0) ownership
    echo "$myuid:x:$myuid:$mygid:anonymous uid:/tmp:/bin/false" >> /etc/passwd
fi

exec "$@"
```

This entrypoint script will automatically provide a passwd file entry for the anonymous uid, so that tools requiring it will not fail.

There is a nice blog post on this and related topics regarding anonymous uids in OpenShift:
https://blog.openshift.com/jupyter-on-openshift-part-6-running-as-an-assigned-user-id/

Answer (score 3):

(I'm keeping this answer because it is useful to know about `nss_wrapper`, however [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45361221/3669757) works without having to install or user nss_wrapper)

Spark wants to be able to look up its UID in passwd.  This integration kink can be resolved using nss_wrapper; a good example of using this solution in the entrypoint for an image can be found here:

https://github.com/radanalyticsio/openshift-spark/blob/master/scripts/spark/added/entrypoint

```
# spark likes to be able to lookup a username for the running UID, if
# no name is present fake it.
cat /etc/passwd > /tmp/passwd
echo "$(id -u):x:$(id -u):$(id -g):dynamic uid:$SPARK_HOME:/bin/false" >> /tmp/passwd

export NSS_WRAPPER_PASSWD=/tmp/passwd
# NSS_WRAPPER_GROUP must be set for NSS_WRAPPER_PASSWD to be used
export NSS_WRAPPER_GROUP=/etc/group

export LD_PRELOAD=libnss_wrapper.so

exec "$@"
```

If you are interested in pre-fab Spark images that can be used on Openshift, I recommend starting here:

https://github.com/radanalyticsio/openshift-spark

These images were generated as part of the tooling for the Radanalytics.io community project, which has produced a lot of tooling for easily creating spark clusters in Openshift.  You can learn more about that project here:

https://radanalytics.io/get-started